# Drools make conflict with spring-security-oauth2-provider

Tags: grails, drools, spring-security-oauth2

I tried to add drools plugin:
https://grails.org/plugin/drools
to my webapp in grails, by just adding it in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7"
    compile ":rest-client-builder:2.0.3"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"
    compile ":spring-security-oauth2-provider:1.0.5.2"
    compile ":browser-detection:0.4.3"
    compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
    compile ":remote-pagination:0.4.8"
    compile ":drools:1.1.0"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.1'
}
```

, but I've received an error:

```
Configuring Spring Security OAuth2 provider ...
... done configuring Spring Security OAuth2 provider Running Common
Auth Plugin... | Error 2015-05-25 13:25:09,499 [localhost-startStop-1]
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the
application: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2ProviderFilter':
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
instantiate bean class
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader Message: Error
creating bean with name 'oauth2ProviderFilter': Instantiation of bean
failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
instantiate bean class
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor |    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^   
745 | run       in java.lang.Thread Caused by
BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter]:
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor |    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^   
745 | run       in java.lang.Thread Caused by NoClassDefFoundError:
com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader
->>  800 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader |    449 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader |     71 | access$100 in    
'' |    361 | run . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1 |    355 | run   
in     '' |    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader |    425 |
loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader |   2615 |
privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class |   2856 | getMethod0 in 
'' |   1668 | getMethod in     '' |    243 | newInstance in
javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder |    235 | newInstance in     '' |    432
| find      in     '' |    637 | newInstance in
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext |    584 | newInstance in     '' |    262 |
run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |   1145 | runWorker in
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor |    615 | run . . . in
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^    745 | run       in
java.lang.Thread Caused by ClassNotFoundException:
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.AnnotationReader
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |    355 | run       in     '' |    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader |    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    800 | defineClass in     '' |    142 | defineClass in
java.security.SecureClassLoader |    449 | defineClass in
java.net.URLClassLoader |     71 | access$100 in     '' |    361 | run
. . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1 |    355 | run       in     '' |   
354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader |    425 | loadClass in
java.lang.ClassLoader |   2615 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in
java.lang.Class |   2856 | getMethod0 in     '' |   1668 | getMethod
in     '' |    243 | newInstance in javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder |   
235 | newInstance in     '' |    432 | find      in     '' |    637 |
newInstance in javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext |    584 | newInstance in   
'' |    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |   1145 |
runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor |    615 | run .
. . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker ^    745 | run  
in java.lang.Thread Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

It seems there is a conflict between Drools and spring-security-oauth2-provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I resolved this issue by adding:

```
compile ":cxf:2.1.1"
```

to BuildConfig plugins.

you can find more details by Ken in his comment: https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-drools/issues/8#issuecomment-105252639